# How to refer to children elements in CSS

Tags: css

I'm not sure if this is even possible but I thought I'd ask. Instead of giving ids to all of my elements under a parent, I'd like to know if in CSS, I can refer to each of them without giving them an id.

If I have:

```
  <td id="bracket-wrapper-lt">
    <div id="bracket-top-lt"></div>
    <div id="bracket-middle-lt"></div>
    <div id="bracket-bottom-lt"></div>
  </td>
```

Can I access the three divs under `bracket-wrapper-lt` giving me the following

```
  <td id="bracket-wrapper-lt">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cross browser support you can also use:

```
#bracket-wrapper-lt > div:first-child { /*Style goes here*/ }
#bracket-wrapper-lt > div:first-child + div { /*Style goes here*/ }
#bracket-wrapper-lt > div:first-child + div + div { /*Style goes here*/ }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sfEDk/

It will work in IE(>=7),Firefox,Chrome,Safari and Opera

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mario. I'm looking at this now

Comment: The more nested CSS you use the more complicated it gets

Comment: You're welcome, I love this method because the selectors don't usually get too long and it works in all the most used browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can, using the `:nth-child(<number>)` css.

See http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/ for details.

Example on your code:

```
  <td id="bracket-wrapper-lt">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </td>
```

CSS:

```
td#bracket-wrapper-lt div:nth-child(1) {
    color: red;
}
```

The above would color the text in your first div red.

Comment: OK, thanks. I stumbled across that last week and honestly, I can't get my head around it. Is there a simple explanation for it?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example

Comment: Wrong selector `td#bracket-wrapper-lt:nth-child(1)` change it..and I'll take my -1 back

Comment: You also have :first-child and :last-child selectors, which could also be usefull in your case.

Comment: Thanks Damien, I've used those before but I just needed something for more than 2.

Comment: Seriously Alien? If you toss your -1's around like that instead of just giving the comment, you can keep your -1..

Comment: @DamienOvereem I just forced you to correct, this is how site works :) I have no issue with your answer, it was wrong so I made you correct it..some people just don't read comments ..

Comment: Usually asking/notifying is more decent then "forcing" .. Thats how real life works.. Enough of that though, lets not pollute.

Comment: Although the code works for the specific markup, a selector like `td#bracket-wrapper-lt div:nth-child(1)` is unnecessarily unsafe. It matches any `div` element that is inside the indicated `td` and is the first side of its parent. To match only the children of `td` element, use the `>` combinator: `td#bracket-wrapper-lt > div:nth-child(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access it using:

```
#bracket-wrapper-lt div
```

matches all descendants (with specified tag, class etc.) and

```
#brakect-wrapper-lt > div
```

matches all children (with specified tag, class etc.)

You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: Edga, can I use this for 3 children? Each child is doing something different in this case so would this still work?

Comment: No, this is for all children that match the selector. If children were with different class or tag then yes. But if you need different style for each of them than nth-child is what you need